# OpenCV.jar library not recognized when importing from it [Java]

Tags: java, opencv, dll, jar

I am using Netbeans and I have a .jar file created by me with CMake than I am now trying to use in my code.
I imported the library in my project, put the dll in the same folder, gave the path to the dll in Run, but when trying to import classes it doesn't recognize them.[image]

[image: Photo of the imports and dependencies]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you, but in IntelliJ IDEA.

You need to import the .dll file as well. It's a Native library.

try:

Project -> Properties -> RUN -> VM Options -> find where the path to the .dll is and press ok

For IntelliJ is as follows:

Instructions:

1. Install OpenCV 4.5.0 from https://opencv.org/releases/
   Later releases might have compatibility issues.
2. Open the file as a project from IntelliJ IDEA
3. Open Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies -> (+) Add -> JARs or Directories (continue step 4)
4. Find the path where you installed the OpenCV 4.5.0 library /opencv/build/java/opencv-450.jar
5. press "OK"
6. In Dependencies (in IntelliJ) find the library, select it, then press the "Edit..." (pen symbol)
7. Press the (+) Add button and go to /opencv/build/java/x64 or x86 and select the .dll file and press "OK"

If you have followed the instructions correctly then the project should compile.

If the problem is not from the OpenCV library then try to reload the Maven Dependencies using the Maven Handler (right hand side of the window)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did what you said even before posting the question. You can see the path to the DLL in VMOptions in the first photo.

Comment: I found sort of a workaround by using a OpenCV.jar file from a random github project and loading my own generated dll with it ( had to rename the dll manually to match the .jar file name) and it worked, at least for the modules my .dll containted.